# MediaPlayer: Prepare failed status 0x1 error while streaming song

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I've problem with streaming some songs in my android application. 
Here is my test code for creating `MadiaPlayer` and setting data source:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://streaming.ibroadcast.com/?file=MjA1MTIyMS0xMDA1NDQ1NC01MDYxNjY5LTEwMDAwMDQ=");  
try {
   mediaPlayer.prepare();
} catch (Exception ex) {
   Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, ex.getMessage(), ex);
}
```

I get this on `mediaPlayer.prepare()`:

```
10-31 15:41:27.130: ERROR/NuCachedSource2(174): source returned error -32, 0 retries left
10-31 15:41:34.388: ERROR/NuCachedSource2(174): source returned error -32, 0 retries left
10-31 15:41:37.371: ERROR/MediaPlayer(5360): error (1, -2147483648)
10-31 15:41:37.381: ERROR/log_tag (5360): Prepare failed.: status=0x1
    java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
```

I've tryed to stream a bunch of songs using this code and this problem occures only for three or four songs, but it's 100% reproducable for that songs. What is more, if I download this songs to SD card and play it from there it plays without any errors. I also able to stream it using browser. All songs has `mp3` format and server response contains headers like this:

```
Accept-Ranges:      bytes
Connection:     close
Content-Length:     5 MB
Content-Type:       audio/mpeg
Date:       2013 Oct 31 14:43:01-8s
ETag:       831c011006861dc9b2fc89ef185f2f4b
Last-Modified:      2013 Aug 28 18:28:31-63d 21h
Server:     Apache/2.2.25 (Amazon)
```

Does anyone has ideas what is wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Here is [not working song](http://pastebin.com/ZP6chRMd) first 1024 bytes and here is [working one](http://pastebin.com/UV1r81vy)

Comment: Could you post here 1024 byte HEX representation of the working and not working mp3 file? You're calling `mediaPlayer.release()` somewhere in your code aren't you? :)

Comment: Sure, I've updated my post with that data. I'm calling `mediaPlayer.release()` in `onCompletion` and `onError` listener, but my application fails before it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After analising HEX samples it reveals that your "working" file is as expected 
`MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3 with ID3v2 Tag (.mp3 file)` but the "not working" one isn't mp3 but `MPEG-1 Audio Layer 2 (.mp2 file)`. According the [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) it isn't supported. It may even have a .mp3 extension but inside it is not a mp3 file.

Comment: I wonder why does this file plays without error when it's loaded to sd card?

Comment: You have to match HEX representation of the checked file against mp3 file signature: http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/PRONOM/Format/proFormatSearch.aspx?status=detailReport&id=687&strPageToDisplay=signatures

Comment: I don't know why does this file plays without error when it's loaded to sd card, but this is only guess I have :).

Comment: I've checked your link and as I understood `MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3 with ID3v2 Tag` files should starts from `49 44 33` bytes, right? But both my files starts from this bytes, I can't see any difference here.

Comment: Start of the file doesn't matter. Mp3 file signature is FFFA or FFFB or FFF3 if I remember correctly. It is repeatable all over the file (in every frame).

Comment: If you want you can post another not working file and I'll check for you.

Comment: Makes sense. Now I see the difference. 
I've checked a few more files and all working has repeating `FF FB` bytes.
Thanks a lot!